# Ordering Vectors, order was not declared in this scope (libraries?)

Tags: c++, vector, containers, libraries

I am trying to order a vector (string) by means of another vector (values, int) which have the same length. Now, the issue appears rather simple to address and my question is not HOW to address this issue, but rather where my bug is, that the following will give me the error "'order' was not declared in this scope" by the compiler.

if x was one vector, and y another, I'd go by, or something similar (as said, this is not the issue):

```
x[sort(order(y.begin(), y.end(), greater<int>()))];
```

or something similar. Now apparently order is not included. I have the following libraries/ containers included:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
```

Now, do I need another library/ container in order to use 'order'?

Comment: You can make an auxiliary vector of indexes `[0, x.size())`, sort *that* vector by reference to the int vector, and then use the sorted elements to access the string vector.

Comment: Or stick everything into a `std::map<int, std::string>`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no function called `order` in the standard library. That's where your bug is.

Some other bugs in that line:

`std::sort` takes 2 or 3 parameters. First and last iterators and optional comparator which matches exactly with the parameters that you pass to `order` now. You are currently passing whatever your `order` returns to `sort`, which is wrong.

`std::sort` returns `void`, so you can't pass it's return value to `operator[]` of `x`.

To do what you want, simplest solution is to put the values in a `std::map<int, std::string>`. And then copy the values to a vector if you really need a vector of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you don't provide a full example and its not clear why you expect the function `order` to be found at all. It's not part of the c++ language syntax itself and there's also no `order` function in the `std` namespace. You also do not provide the `order` function yourself. So the compiler is totally right telling you that *"'order' was not declared in this scope"*.

Further, assuming that the `sort` function is meant to be `std::sort`, this will not work either. [std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/%20sort) expects 2 or 3 parameters and does not return any value, so there will be no index to reference any value within the `x` vector.